# tr -s fails to compress consecutive spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tr

Here is a snippet of a text file I am trying to manipulate:

```
845136006577              1.0
845136006638              4.0
845136006676              6.0
845136007895              3.0
845136007970              7.0
845136008052              9.0
845136008175              4.0
845136008298              4.0
845136008373              4.0
845136008410              4.0
845136008557              3.0
845136008595              4.0
```

I am trying to compress all spaces on each line down to a single `,` (comma).

Here is what I have tried:

`tr -s '[:space:]' ',' < file.txt`

`tr -s ' ' ',' < file.txt`

But the output always looks like this:

```
845136006577,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1.0,
845136006638,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4.0,
845136006676,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6.0,
845136007895,,,,,,,,,,,,,,3.0,
845136007970,,,,,,,,,,,,,,7.0,
845136008052,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9.0,
845136008175,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4.0,
845136008298,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4.0,
845136008373,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4.0,
```

Do I have a potential encoding issue with my file? Something is not right.

**UPDATE**

Snippet of output from `xxd < file.txt`:

```
00003b0: 3600 3000 3000 3800 3500 3500 3700 2000  6.0.0.8.5.5.7. .
00003c0: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
00003d0: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 3300 2e00 3000   . . . . .3...0.
00003e0: 2000 0a00 3800 3400 3500 3100 3300 3600   ...8.4.5.1.3.6.
00003f0: 3000 3000 3800 3500 3900 3500 2000 2000  0.0.8.5.9.5. . .
0000400: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
0000410: 2000 2000 2000 2000 3400 2e00 3000 2000   . . . .4...0. .
0000420: 0a00 3800 3400 3500 3100 3300 3600 3000  ..8.4.5.1.3.6.0.
0000430: 3000 3800 3600 3900 3400 2000 2000 2000  0.8.6.9.4. . . .
0000440: 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000   . . . . . . . .
0000450: 2000 2000 2000 3500 2e00 3000 2000 0a00   . . .5...0. ...
0000460: 3800 3400 3500 3100 3300 3600 3000 3000  8.4.5.1.3.6.0.0.
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. `-s` is squeeze repeats.

Comment: Yes there is something wrong with the file, works fine for me. Also you may consider using `[:blank:]` instead of `[:space:]` to preserve newlines(assuming you want to)

Comment: @123 You are right. Removing my comments

Comment: @phirschybar Can you run `xxd < file` and post the output in your question?

Comment: @123 updating post with output of `xxd`

Comment: It looks like you're reading that UTF-16 as if it were ASCII, UTF-8 or ISO-8859.

Comment: @TobySpeight ok I suspected it was an encoding issue. do you recommend another bash command to convert the file before attempting to run `tr -s`?

Comment: I'm trying out some solutions right now.  Will update my answer soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the file is full of null characters you can just remove them before processing with tr(assuming you don't want any null chars in there).

With tr twice

```
tr -d '\0' < file | tr -s '[:blank:]' ','
```

With single perl

```
perl -pe 's/\x00//g;s/[[:blank:]]+/,/' file
```

Or if you want to preserve your encoding

```
perl -pe 's/([[:blank:]]\x00)+/,\x00/g' file
```

or probably most robustly, you can set the encoding for perl to read.

```
perl -Mopen=":std,:encoding(utf-16le)" -pe 's/[[:blank:]]+/,/g' test
```

Comment: Toby's answer was also a good approach. But this one directly solves the problem and works for my case. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to suggest the Perl approach (with `:encoding`) but got dragged into Real Life, so thanks for including that.

Answer (score 2):

Your input is encoded as UTF-16 (or UCS-2), but you're reading it as if it were ASCII (or UTF-8, ISO-8859 or similar), so you see alternate ASCII and null values.

So the spaces all appear to be separated by NUL and won't be coalesced.

One workaround is to pipeline through `iconv` and back (assuming you want the result in the same encoding):

```sh
iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 \
    | tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' \
    | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16
```

Obviously, if you want your output to be in UTF-8, you can skip the final re-encode step.

You can't make `tr` or other standard utilities work natively with UTF-16 or UCS-2, so this is probably the best approach if you don't want to change to Perl or Python.

Comment: UTF-16 locales don't exist for Linux because encoded strings are not C compatible.

Comment: Thanks, @thatotherguy; I was discovering that as you typed!  I'll edit to incorporate that information

Comment: @TobySpeight If i run this command it inserts `fffe` at the start of the file?

Comment: Yes @123 (because we aren't privy to show the start of the hexdump, we can't tell whether it started with or without a byte-order-mark).  You can use `utf-16be` or `utf-16le` (as appropriate) for streams without a BOM.

Comment: @TobySpeight Just thought it was weird it inserts it, when it accepts input without it. Don't use iconv much, is there a way to specify endianness?